# Problema con tipos incompatibles (dobles punteros)

Tags: c, punteros

Me surge la duda teniendo la siguiente funcion que pide un doble puntero:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    prueba(void **ap)
{
    *ap = NULL;
}
```

con el siguiente main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    prueba(void **ap);

int        main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    prueba(&str);
    if (str == NULL)
        printf("NULL");
    return (0);
}
```

Al compilar, gcc me saca el siguiente warning:

```
main2.c:11:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'void **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        prueba(&str);
               ^~~~
main2.c:4:23: note: passing argument to parameter 'ap' here
void    prueba(void **ap);
```

La duda viene de que con simples punteros esto no ocurre, por ejemplo, con la siguiente funcion y main respectivamente gcc compila correctamente, a pesar de pasar un puntero a char a una funcion que pide un puntero void:

funcion:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    prueba(void *ap)
{
    ap = NULL;
}
```

main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    prueba(void *ap);

int        main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    prueba(str);
    if (str == NULL)
        printf("NULL");
    return (0);
}
```

A que se debe que con punteros simples se pueda pero con dobles no?

Answer (score 0):

En el primer caso al compilar **se produce un warning porque estás pasando un dato tipo (char **) a un (void **)**, que son tipos distintos. Pero solo es un warning, el programa compila y funciona correctamente.

Si quieres evitar el warning **tienes que hacer casting** así:

```
prueba((void **)&str);
```

De este modo le dices al compilador que convierta el puntero (char **) a (void **) antes de pasarlo a la función, que espera precisamente un (void **) y por ello no da Warning por incompatibilidad de tipos.

En la segunda versión de tu código, donde utilizas punteros simples, desconozco por qué no da Warning pero **ten cuidado porque es incorrecto y no hará lo que esperas.** Al utilizar punteros simples la función prueba NO modificará la variable str del main, si no una copia local llamada ap, que al fin y al cabo no hace nada.

Veamos un ejemplo más sencillo con variables int. En el código de abajo el valor de la variable 'a' del main se copia a la variable 'x' de la función 'prueba'. La clave está en que **se copia el valor, pero a y x son variables independientes**. Por ello cuando 'prueba' aumenta 'x' en 1, la variable 'a' no se ve afectada de ninguna manera. Es decir, prueba tal y como está creada aquí no hace nada útil.

```
void prueba(int x) {
    x = x + 1;
}

void main() {
    int a = 0;
    prueba(a); // le pasamos el valor de a
    printf("%d",a); // imprime 0, ¡mal!
}
```

**La forma correcta de hacerlo es usar punteros**. Modificamos el código para pasarle a 'prueba' un puntero a entero, de modo que desde 'prueba' podamos acceder directamente a la zona de memoria de la variable 'a'. Así sí aumentamos el valor de 'a' en 1.

```
void prueba(int *x) {
    *x = *x + 1; // modificamos la zona de memoria a la que apunta x
}

void main() {
    int a = 0;
    prueba(&a); // le pasamos la dirección de memoria de a
    printf("%d",a); // imprime 1, ¡bien!
}
```

Volviendo al caso original de tu pregunta, la variable 'str' que utilizas ya es por sí misma un puntero 'char *'. Para pasárselo a la función prueba y que, como en el ejemplo anterior, modifique la variable 'str' del main, necesitas usar un puntero a puntero, es decir un 'char **'. De lo contrario la función 'prueba' no hará nada porque en lugar de modificar la variable 'str' del main simplemente modificará una copia local independiente de 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

En **Lenguaje C y C++** existen varios tipos de punteros, por mencionar algunos tenemos:

1. Puntero común, ejemplo: `int *ptr;`
2. Puntero a puntero, ejemplo: `int **ptr2, ***ptr3, ****ptr4, *****ptr5;` etc.
3. Puntero a un array constante, ejemplo: `int (*ptr)[5];`
4. Puntero genérico, ejemplo: `void *ptr;`
5. Etc.

A como te mencione en el punto 4, `void*` es un puntero genérico.

**¿Qué significa esto?**

1. `void*` es un tipo de datos donde puedes asignar cualquier tipo de puntero **(dirección de memoria)**, ejemplo:

Lenguaje C/C++

```
char     *nombre_de_algo = ...;
int      *array_dinamico = ...;
char    **lista_de_palabras = ...;
double  **tabla_de_multiplicar = ...;
char   ***tabla_de_palabras = ...;
void     *puntero_generico = NULL;
struct tm tiempo = { };
puntero_generico = nombre_de_algo;       // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = array_dinamico;       // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = lista_de_palabras;    // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = tabla_de_multiplicar; // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = tabla_de_palabras;    // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = &tiempo;              // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = printf;               // No advertencia, no error
puntero_generico = fopen;                // No advertencia, no error
```

2. En el caso de **Lenguaje C** un `void*` cuando es asignado a otra variable de tipo puntero distinto de `void*`, este se convierte implícitamente al tipo que se esta asignando y en el caso de **Lenguaje C++** requiere un **cast explícito**, ejemplo:

Lenguaje C:

```
int   numero = 15;
int  *puntero_a_numero  = &numero;
void *puntero_generico  = puntero_a_numero; // No hay advertencia del compilador
int  *puntero_a_numero2 = puntero_generico; // No hay advertencia del compilador
```

Lenguaje C++

```
int   numero = 15;
int  *puntero_a_numero  = &numero;
void *puntero_generico  = puntero_a_numero; // No hay advertencia del compilador
int  *puntero_a_numero2 = puntero_generico; // Error de compilación
```

---

Retomando el segundo punto recibes una advertencia cuando asignas `char**` a un `void**`. De los tipos de punteros que te mencione `void**` cae en el segundo punto, es decir, es un puntero a puntero, no un puntero genérico, para el compilador son tipos diferentes y lanza la advertencia.

Este comportamiento genera una pregunta interesante:

**¿Porqué una advertencia y no un error, no se supone que son tipos diferentes?** 
En realidad todo los punteros a punteros solo tienen una diferencia, esta es simplemente el tipo en el que fueron declarados, de ahí todos tienen exactamente el mismo funcionamiento, el que nos interesa es que todos tienen la misma aritmética de punteros sin importar el tipo, esto se debe a que todos los punteros usan la misma cantidad de bytes en memoria, normalmente *4/8 bytes*, ejemplo:

```
printf(" %lu\n %lu\n %lu\n %lu\n %lu\n %lu\n %lu\n ",
    sizeof(void*),                     // 4/8 bytes
    sizeof(&printf),                   // 4/8 bytes
    sizeof(int**********************), // 4/8 bytes
    sizeof(int(*)[100]),               // 4/8 bytes
    sizeof(void**),                    // 4/8 bytes
    sizeof(char**),                    // 4/8 bytes
    sizeof(double(*)(int, ...)));      // 4/8 bytes
```

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior podemos decir que `char**`, `void**`, `int**`, `double**`, `otro_tipo_t**`, etc. son tipos equivalentes, pero recuerda usar siempre el **cast explícito** para evitar la advertencia, demostrémoslo con un ejemplo:

Solo Lenguaje C (Código no válido en C++)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void set_null_using_void_pointer(void **ptr)
{
    *ptr = NULL;
}

void set_null_using_double_pointer(double **ptr)
{
    set_null_using_void_pointer(ptr); // advertencia, tipos incompatibles double** a void**
}

typedef struct { } struct_t;

void set_null_using_struct_t_pointer(struct_t **ptr)
{
    set_null_using_double_pointer(ptr); // advertencia, tipos incompatibles struct_t** a double**
}

void set_value_using_struct_t_pointer(struct_t **ptr, size_t bytes)
{
    *ptr = malloc(bytes); // cast implícito de void* a struct_t**
}

void free_using_float_pointer(float **ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    set_null_using_struct_t_pointer(ptr); // advertencia, tipos incompatibles float** a struct_t**
}

int main()
{
    int valor = 100;
    int *ptr_valor = &valor;
    printf("%p\n", ptr_valor); // escribe: 0x7ffe5e94afa4
    set_null_using_struct_t_pointer(&ptr_valor); // advertencia, tipos incompatibles int** a struct_t**
    printf("%p\n", ptr_valor); // escribe: (nil)
    set_value_using_struct_t_pointer(&ptr_valor, sizeof(int)); // advertencia, tipos incompatibles int** a struct_t**
    *ptr_valor = 150 + valor;
    printf("%p - value: %d\n", ptr_valor, *ptr_valor); // 0x18d8010 - value: 250
    free_using_float_pointer(&ptr_valor); // advertencia, tipos incompatibles int** a float**
    printf("%p\n", ptr_valor); // escribe: (nil)
    return 0;
}
```

Si corres el código veras que no lanza errores, ni comportamiento indefinido y todo funciona como lo esperado, aunque los punteros sean de diferente tipos todos usan la misma cantidad de memoria, que es lo único que nos interesa para manipular e interpretar los datos como queramos.